# Custom ParmaLink in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, permalinks

Is it possible to have custom Permalink in Tumblr using newDayDate "tag"? Instead of [existing Permalink format](http://subdomain.tumblr.com/post/3434343/title-title),
I want inclusion of year/month/date as well in post perma link ([for example](http://subdomain.tumblr.com/post/2012/10/24/title-title)), just like WordPress default permalink format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Tumblr support and received following response from them:

> I'm sorry, but that isn't supported at this time. Our apologies. We
>   will share your desire for this feature with our team.